# mac & windows backup solutions - Offsite Backups

Tags: windows, macos, backup

Im looking for some advice on a system Im looking to impliment within our company, but so far I have not found an adequate solution too.

I need to provide my users with a way to backup there laptops whilst in the office and if possible offsite as well, we have a mixture of Windows & Mac laptops so software should ideally be multi platform. This is the first time i am attempting to-do something like this as we normally charge the users with responsibility for their backups.

I have ruled out most of the services like dropbox, sugarsync (unless one exists that does this) as whilst they does exactly what I want it does not give me any control over restoring / recovering data in the event of the user being unavailable, as it requires their account password to access data.

Comment: Why can't you sync a folder on the server to each account, so that you have a local copy stored?

Comment: we have users in the field who are very rarely in contact with the office so it would make backups for them virtually impossible. where as an internet connection for them would suffice for a cloud based system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK to answer this question (thanks for all the replies btw) Our company decided upon a product from a company called BackupDirect. it allows centralised backups / restores of data from clients and servers and is very easy to get working and lightweight on our bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I you want a program that fits these discriptions, you might want to look at [SparkeShare](http://sparkleshare.org/). Free, open source, and you can set everything to sync with your server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BackBlaze.com](http://www.backblaze.com/internet-backup.html)

Not sure if it has an option for a master password, but if you are dealing with business data the account passwords of all the employee's backup accounts should all be recorded and managed by the person handling your backup solution anyway.